# Using variables in Nginx

Tags: nginx

My vhosts follow a common logic and I'm trying to define as much as I can about it in the "server" directive within the nginx.conf instead of the single domain.conf in the conf.d/ directory.
In order to achieve this I'm using variables but they are not being evaluted.
Here an example involving the server name and its aliases using the $host variable.
But in my php script the variable is reported as its name, not as its value:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  $host *.$host;
        charset utf-8;

        access_log  /var/log/$host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   /var/www/$host;
            index  app.php index.php index.html home.php home.html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            root           /var/www/$host;
            fastcgi_index  app.php;
            include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        }

        location ~ /\. {
            deny  all;
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Array
(    
    [SERVER_NAME] => $host
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
server {
    server_name ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;
    # ....
}
```

Then force the domain to be the `SERVER_NAME`

```
fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $domain;
```

Keep in mind this won't include the `www` part, if you want to include it in the domain name

```
server_name ~^(?<domain>.+)$;
```

Comment: and then again with the same regexp to define the root? :(

Comment: nope, turns into     [SERVER_NAME] => ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$

Comment: that's kinda strange, what's your nginx version